# Typescript Reflect-MetaData in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, reflect-metadata

Does anyone have any examples of how to use reflect-metadata in nodejs? I am using atom-typescript also. I downloaded using it via npm but i keep getting random errors. I see Reflect is a blank object. Just looking for an example of how to incorporate this into a module or node project.

Comment: No answer provided below is the right answer? Can you please add more details on what you're trying to achieve and why the below answers are not satisfying your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript@2.0+, you can use it like this:

```
npm i -S reflect-metadata
npm i -D @types/reflect-metadata

// your.ts
import 'reflect-metadata'
Reflect.getMetadata(...)
Reflect.metadata(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

When I faced the same problem and nothing worked, I opened Reflect.ts file in node_modules. At the end, you can see it hooking Reflect at global level.

```
// hook global Reflect
(function(__global: any) {
    if (typeof __global.Reflect !== "undefined") {
        if (__global.Reflect !== Reflect) {
            for (var p in Reflect) {
                __global.Reflect[p] = (<any>Reflect)[p];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        __global.Reflect = Reflect;
    }
})(
    typeof window !== "undefined" ? window :
        typeof WorkerGlobalScope !== "undefined" ? self :
            typeof global !== "undefined" ? global :
                Function("return this;")());
```

So, I removed require reflect-metadata from all other files, and moved it to main file.

```
require('reflect-metadata/Reflect');
```

Now, I can use it inside all modules (without requiring reflect-metadata) with the following syntax,

```
(<any>global).Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key); // In Typescript
```

EDIT:
We can also reference reflect-metadata.d.ts file from node_modules and then use the API directly.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts" />

Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey);
```

Comment: Wow this really sucks. Not your answer- but man everything es6-import typescript has to be a huge pain for no reason. No one can just use the same pattern.